# The logic behind the "There is 1 additional version" from apt list

Tags: apt

Trying to understand the seemingly inconsistent behavior of `apt list` in regards to different packages on my Xubuntu 20.04.

Let's consider the two packages, `blueman` and `xterm`, both `installed,automatic`, both having received some updates after initial installation:

```
$ apt list blueman
Listing... Done
blueman/focal-updates,focal-security,now 2.1.2-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
$ apt list blueman -a
Listing... Done
blueman/focal-updates,focal-security,now 2.1.2-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
blueman/focal 2.1.2-1 amd64

$ apt list xterm
Listing... Done
xterm/focal-updates,focal-security,now 353-1ubuntu1.20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xterm/focal-updates,focal-security 353-1ubuntu1.20.04.2 i386
$ apt list xterm -a
Listing... Done
xterm/focal-updates,focal-security,now 353-1ubuntu1.20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xterm/focal 353-1ubuntu1 amd64

xterm/focal-updates,focal-security 353-1ubuntu1.20.04.2 i386
xterm/focal 353-1ubuntu1 i386
```

Thus, although `xterm` seems to have *even more* additional versions than `blueman`, the abovementioned suggestion note is only included for the latter, not the former.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn’t really explain the logic, but the implementation of `apt list` [only shows the notice if the following two conditions are met](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/0d25ce3d466ecddea02d171981f011f7dbf95e08/apt-private/private-list.cc#L151):

- there are more versions to show;
- and only *one* version was shown so far.

On your system, `xterm` is listed for two architectures, so it is displayed in two “versions” (the same version on two architectures) fails the second condition.